# $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin (n x) / n^2 $ not differentiable at $x=0 $.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Apparently, by Weierstrass' test, this function is continuous. How to prove that it is not differentiable at $x=0$? I plotted its graph. It seems that

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f}{x} =\infty . $$

How to prove it?

Term-by-term differentiation is not necessarily valid here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One can show (by using Abel's summation and the Taylor series of the main branch of the logarithm) that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n} = -\log(2\sin(x/2))$$
for $ 0 < x < \pi$ and the convergence is uniform on any interval $[a,b]$ with $0<a<b<\pi$. Thus we find for $x>0$ that (by interchanging integration and summation)
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \frac{1}{h} \int_x^{x+h} -\ln(2 \sin(t/2))  dx.$$
One can check that the integrand on the right-hand side is absolute integrable, say on $[0,\pi]$. Thus the the integral as a function of $x$ is contionous in $x=0$. We get
$$\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \frac{1}{h} \int_0^{h} - \ln(2 \sin(t/2)) \,  dt.$$
Since $t/2 \le 2 \sin(t/2) \le t$  for $h \in [0,\pi/2]$ and $x \mapsto \log(x)$ is monotone on $(0,1]$, we can compare the growth of the last integral with
$$\frac{1}{h} \int_0^{h} \ln(t) \, dt = \ln(h)-1.$$
Thus
$$\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} \sim -\ln(h)$$
for $h \downarrow 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible to get the asymptotic behavior of f as $x \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: $-x\log x$ by integrating the series above and noting that near $0$, $2\sin{\frac{x}{2}}$~$x$